# Find out total number of cores on a Win Server 2008 cluster system

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a way to find out the total number of cores available on Server 2008 cluster system? i.e. total number of cores on all compute nodes? Is there an environment variable that has this information?

Thanks,

AG

Answer (score 1):

No. You have tp program a script, run through all machiens and count the processors on them (available remotely via WMI).